# spring not enforcing method security annotations

Tags: java, annotations, spring-security

I'm some what lost as to why spring isn't enforcing the @Secured("ROLE_USER") on my service interface.  My controllers are established using annotations.

An example of my service Interface

```
public interface MyServiceManager {

    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    public void delete(int cid);

    @RolesAllowed({"ROLE_USER"})
    public Contact getContact(int contactId);
}
```

my security-context:

```
<global-method-security   secured-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled">
</global-method-security>

<http auto-config="true" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_SUPERVISOR" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/addcontact**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <concurrent-session-control max-sessions="1"
        exception-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/welcome.do" logout-url="/logout"/>
</http>
    <authentication-provider>
    <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
    <user-service>
        <user name="rod" password="a564de63c2d0da68cf47586ee05984d7" authorities="ROLE_SUPERVISOR, ROLE_USER, ROLE_TELLER" />
    </user-service>
</authentication-provider>
```

Answer (score 7):

Do you have the statement

```
<global-method-security   secured-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled" />
```

in the same configuration file as the one you defined the MyServiceManager bean? I had the same problem until I turned on debug for org.springframework, and noticed that spring security was only applied on the same file as the ones where global-method-security was defined in.

Comment: I'm importing the security-context.xml and datasource-context.xml into the applicationContext.xml.  Moving up <context:annotation-config /> seemed to fix the url path security role issue. but not the method security issue.

Comment: Yes, the important part is that you have the global-method-security in the same Spring context as the components.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the exact location of this statement:

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" >
```

proved to be very important. Make sure that you put it **after** you declare which classes should be scanned and used as controllers.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.controller" />
```

This is the way to make sure that the @Secured annotations will also get into the game

Comment: It's not so important that it be after the component-scan, it just has to be in the same file!

Answer (score 2):

After doing more research on this problem I came to the following conclusion/solution.  I'm not sure if it's 100% correct..but it works.

I put all of my configuration in the dispatcher-servlet.xml file.  So instead of having a disptacher-servlet.xml and application-context.xml.  The dispatcher-servlet.xml is loaded by the application (contextConfigLocation).  Within the dispatcher-servlet.xml I import my security-context.xml and datasource-context.xml.   Afer that, everything works.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem.  Using the information from Kent Lai's reply here, I was able to fix it.

I put the `<global-method-security>` element in my `app-servlet.xml` but kept the security definitions separate in `security.xml`, where `web.xml` has `contextConfigLocation` for `app-servlet.xml` and `security.xml`.

Works like a charm now!

Comment: The way I understood this it's a bit redundant to define your app-servlet.xml file as part of the contextConfigLocation. If you use DispatcherServlet it will load your servletname-servlet.xml which inherits the WebApplicationContext. In this case it seems to me that your beans will first be created once in your WebApplicationContext by your ContextLoader and then overridden with the same definitions another time by your DispatcherServlet.

Comment: @Sam and @Joe Actually its not redundant because they do separate things. If you put the -servlet.xml route a child application context will be created whose parent is the WebApplicationContext. @Joe probably got it to work because he has no child context (app-servlet and security are in the same context).

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the annotations on the implementation class instead of the interface and see if that works.  I ended up doing that on a recent project because I was also using the @Transactional attribute on my service layer, and the Spring docs recommend putting those on the class and not the interface.  I don't know if the same issue might apply to @Secured, but I wanted to keep the annotations in the same place.  See the [Spring Docs](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

Regarding Kent Lai's answer...that is a good idea...make sure that your security config file is actually being included by Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use something like this in your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>name</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I'm not sure why, but if I use the DispatcherServlet I was not able to enforce Security annotations

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.
After I added:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

in my spring-security.xml file it disappeared.

Hope this will help someone :)