# Security annotation - can't secure

Tags: java, spring-security, roles

I have a problem using : `@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})` above a protected method.

I am logged in with ROLE_EMPLOYEE and I still able run methods annotated with: `@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})`

this is my config:

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
<bean id="affiliatesApi" class="com.affiliates.api.AffiliatesApi" />
```

this is my  AffiliatesApi class

```
public  class AffiliatesApi extends BaseApplicationAPI<Object> {
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
    public ResultContainer getAll(IFilter filter) {
        ISecurityFilter securityFilter = (ISecurityFilter)SecurityUtills.getSecurityFilter();
        return affiliateDao.getAll(Affiliate.class,securityFilter,filter);
    }
}
```

I am calling the affiliatesAPI from another package as the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/affiliates")
public class AffiliatesController extends BaseController{

    @Resource(name="affiliatesApi")
    AffiliatesApi affiliatesApi = new AffiliatesApi();

         @RequestMapping(value = "/get" )
     public ModelAndView get(@RequestParam(value="id",required=false ) String){
            affiliatesApi.getAll(filter);
        }
}
```

this is my entire security:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 

            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
        access-denied-page="/Management/auth/denied">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/Management/auth/login"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/Management/main/admin"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_EMPLOYEE')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/Management/api/affiliates/**"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_EMPLOYEE')" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/Management/auth/login/"
            authentication-failure-url="/Management/auth/login?error=true"
            login-processing-url="/Management/auth/j_spring_security_check"
            default-target-url="/Management/auth/login?error=false" />
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/Management/auth/login/" logout-url="/Management/auth/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"
        id="passwordEncoder" />


    <bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.affiliates.service.CustomUserDetailsService" />


    <bean id="affiliatesApi" class="com.affiliates.api.AffiliatesApi" />


</beans>
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j-myapp.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Management/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

This is the excepton i am getting while loading the tom cat:

```
Mar 7, 2011 5:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'affiliatesController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'affiliatesApi' must be of type [com.affiliates.api.AffiliatesApi], but was actually of type [$Proxy44]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5004)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:4999)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'affiliatesApi' must be of type [com.affiliates.api.AffiliatesApi], but was actually of type [$Proxy44]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:409)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:297)
    ... 21 more
```

spring servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Declare a view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [spring not enforcing method security annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517527/spring-not-enforcing-method-security-annotations)

Comment: Why did you close it????

Comment: @fatnjazzy Can you check that affiliatesApi bean is called within the same application context, in which you have defined the spring security?

Comment: @fatnjazzy AffiliatesController will obviousbly be in dispatcher servlet's application context. Is the security context in the same context or is it in root context? Please see http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=65968

Comment: I dont understand your question... but i added my web.xml to my post

Comment: @fatnjazzy The configuration defined by contextConfigLocation context param and loaded by ContextLoaderListener is usually called root application context. You can also configure application context for dispatcher servlet by passing contextConfigLocation init param. By default Dispatcher servlet builds its context from [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory. Since your servlet name is spring, do you have spring-servlet.xml in WEB-INF directory? If yes, can you add that too in question?

Comment: @fatnjazzy no problems. How are you wiring controllers? Are you using <context:component-scan> in WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml? if yes, it should be moved to spring-servlet.xml.

Comment: this is how: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.affiliates" />`  But i cant put it in the spring-servlet.xml. I get: `The prefix "context" for element "context:component-scan" is not bound.` thanks

Comment: @fatnjazz ok. Can you add context namaespace in spring-servlet.xml? Top part of xml will look like this: 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

Comment: Can you post it in answer? it is endign in the middle. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified spring-servlet.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <!-- Declare a view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!- scan annotated controllers -->
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.affiliates" /

</beans>
```

Comment: No luck... If you have the time, this is my project... fatnjazzy.byethost8.com/Affiliates.tar.gz Thanks anyway for your time

Comment: Sorry, now it is working but only in the Controller itselfe and not in a ddeper layers, is that normal?

Comment: @fatnjazzy I was kind of expecting it. We need to review other wirings and use &lt;context:component-scan&gt; in applicationContext.xml as well. What are other stereotypes (@Component, @Service etc.) are you using in non-controller classes?

Comment: Basically all known hibernate such as @entity, @OneToMany @Id @Column and so

Comment: After fixing the servlet there is no error, it is just been ignored