# Spring security: forcing https using annotations?

Tags: java, spring-security

The spring security docs state (2.3.2):

> If your application supports both HTTP
>   and HTTPS, and you require that
>   particular URLs can only be accessed
>   over HTTPS, then this is directly
>   supported using the requires-channel
>   attribute on :

```
  <http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="any"/>
    ...
  </http>
```

But I'm using annotations on my controllers, not intercept-url elements.

- Can I enforce HTTPS selectively via annotations?
- Can I force HTTP for non-secure pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the available docs, it appears that using *only* annotations it may not be possible to enforce channel security.

Comment: It sure seems like the only way to do it is via intercept-url, which seems to undermine annotations (I've annotated all my controllers and not used intercept-url to this point, guess I'll have to backtrack). Thanks for offering your confirmation of this, it's quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of examples that show how to use annotation with Spring Security

http://www.jroller.com/habuma/entry/method_level_security_in_spring

[spring not enforcing method security annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517527/spring-not-enforcing-method-security-annotations)

I don't understand what you mean by forcing HTTP for non-secure pages. If it is non-secure, then it is HTTP already.

Comment: I didn't catch any points in those links specifically about how to force the user to HTTPS using **only** annotations. And regarding HTTP, I was thinking of downgrading users to HTTP when the transition from secure pages (such as account pages) back to the normal non-secure pages (as a way to keep HTTPS traffic to the minimum necessary).

Comment: @David: It's easiest to partition pages into secure and insecure by gross URL (so much easier to get right!) and if you want to downgrade from HTTPS to HTTP when going back to insecure, do note that you can use `requires-channel="http"` to do that.